# Some really insane values in sys part of process' timing

Tags: time

```
real    108m1.284s
user    108m51.617s
sys     307445734m57.875s
```

— **307445734** min 57.875s is something really went crazy. Linux kernel 3.1.5 x86_64. A pitty thing regarding this issue is it's hard to search on web since keywords are quite irrelevant to this very problem.

Comment: Beware that there could be two `time`s in your system, `/usr/bin/time` and possibly the `bash` built-in command (maybe other shells have one, too).  So maybe the respectively other one works fine.  Is it consistent behavior or a one-time thing?  ([Also there are other ways to measure things, e.g. Systemtap](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Systemtap)]

Comment: @sr_, it's a built-in, usually. But nevermind, the reason is kernel, not user space. I'm in email exchange with kernel devs now, we'll see…

Comment: @sr_, the issue's found.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

— [BFS](http://ck.kolivas.org/patches/bfs/)'s [bug.](http://poige.livejournal.com/520776.html)